# How can I listen to a RoutedEvent from a class that doesn't derive from FrameworkElement ? Can it be done?

Tags: wpf, routed-events

The question says it all basically.

I want in a

```
class MyClass
```

to listen to a routed event. Can it be done ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I wiredup the event the wrong way :|

I had

```
EventManager.RegisterClassHandler ( typeof ( MyClass )......
```

Instead of

```
EventManager.RegisterClassHandler ( typeof ( TheClassThatOwnedTheEvent )
```

So .. my bad.

Answer (score 0):

If you can create an *inner* class of MyClass (call it MyInnerClass) that derives from FrameworkElement while retaining the capability to access an enclosing MyClass object, your problem will be solved. You can then implement a 'getListener' method within MyClass that returns the embedded MyInnerClass that you will use to actually listen to events.